# Remove duplicated records in sphinx without doing setGroupBy?

Tags: php, sphinx

Hey I am new to sphinx search.

In my query I retrieve course_ids. All the courses belong to a theme_id, but some of them can belong to more than 1 theme, so some of them are duplicated.

I set limits to my query to display results from 1-20, then 21-40... So 20 by 20.
But sometimes in those 20 results there are duplicated results, so for example if from 21 from 40 there are 3 duplicated results I want to remove them and then fill the 3 empty spaces with the next 3 results, so the query returns instead 21-43. Then 44-64...

I tried setGroupBy(), and it worked, but I don't want the courses to be sorted by course_id but with setSortMode(), so the course_ids are again duplicated.

How can I remove the duplicated records and keep the sorting?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setGroupBy has a third and option argument, to specify the **final** sort order.

So can group by (for example) course_ids but still do the final sorting by weight (or whatever), rather than the default '@group desc'.

```
$client->setSortOrder( SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE );
$client->setGroupBy( 'course_id', SPH_GROUPBY_ATTR,  "@weight desc" );
```

Still use setSortOrder, which determins WHICH of the rows from the course, is kept. Ie show the highest rank one first, which mimicks overall sorting of weight.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you are looking for is exactly what REMOVE_REPEATS() does. Not sure it's available in the programming language clients. You'll probably need to use SphinxQL instead which is anyway recommended as the clients are outdated and miss a lot of functionality.

Here's an example:

Without REMOVE_REPEATS():

```
MySQL [(none)]> select * from testrt;
+------+------+
| id   | gid  |
+------+------+
|    1 |   10 |
|    2 |   10 |
|    3 |   20 |
|    4 |   30 |
|    5 |   30 |
+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

With REMOVE_REPEATS() by gid:

```
MySQL [(none)]> select remove_repeats((select * from testrt), gid, 0,10);
+------+------+
| id   | gid  |
+------+------+
|    1 |   10 |
|    3 |   20 |
|    4 |   30 |
+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

Comment: One issue with `remove_repeats` it doesnt update `total_found`. And also paging is complicated, as the table function runs on the resultset taking into account the inner 'LIMIT', even the implicit `LIMIT 20`. So need to make the inner LIMIT bigger than the rows needed before deduplicating. So to actully get 10 rows in final, may need the inner limit set to say 30 (Allowing for 20 filtered rows).